# Confusion in the definition of direct product of finite groups

Tags: direct-sum

Let $G$ be a finite group. We will say that $G=A \times B \times C$ if

1. A,B,C are normal in $G$
2. $A\cap B \cap C ={e}$
3. $|G|=|A||B||C|$

Is the first condition ok? or should I say $A \times B$ is normal in $G$ and $C$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

That is satisfied if $G$ is an elementary Abelian group of order $8$,
$A=\{e,a\}$, $B=\{e,b\}$ and $C=\{e,ab\}$ where $a$ and $b$ are distinct elements
of order two. But in this case the natural homomorphism from $A\times B\times C$
to $G$ is not an isomorphism.

In this case the subgroups "$A\times B$", "$A\times C$" and "$B\times C$"
are all normal in $G$ too.

Comment: I did not get your answer. In general, Is first condition fine?

Comment: In an Abelian group **all** subgroups are normal. @I_wil_break_wall

Comment: My question is what are the conditions for $G$ can be written as a direct product of three subgroups.